# Getting Error #1502 when it shouldn't have happened

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gsap

I started getting a lot of #1502 errors in my game. ("script executed for too long") Different flash player versions, different users, random places in the game. I can't reproduce it myself.

I collect game logs in case of the uncaught errors and according to them the users have interacted with the game just a few seconds before this error has occurred. This is what bothers me and this is why I'm asking this question. This can't be right. In case of this error they shouldn't be able to interact with it for at least 15 seconds as far as I understand.

And it's not just one case. All these new errors (hundreds per day) have at least one user action logged 1-10 seconds before the error.

At first I thought the time stamp is wrong. I use `getTimer()` to get it. I've inserted `while (true)` loop in the game to test this and verified that the time stamp is correct and happens 15 seconds after the action that started the loop that caused the #1502 error.

This error may be connected to TweenLite since all stack traces look like this:

```
Error: Error #1502
    at com.greensock.core::SimpleTimeline/renderTime()
    at com.greensock::TweenLite$/updateAll()
```

The version of TweenLite which I use isn't the most up to date, but I've used it for 1.5 years in this game and it didn't have issues before. Unfortunately I can't update to the most recent version since it's not backward compatible and will require massive changes.

**UPD To be clear, the question is** "How can I get #1502 error if the user was able to interact with the game just a few seconds before it?"

Comment: You should provide [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without the example it's hard to say why this error happens.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this error. I've provided the stack trace that I get.

Comment: You have an infinite loop or something like that, but we can not help you without code.

Comment: If I had an infinite loop how could the user trigger an action in the middle of it? Because he did. At least according to the log which I tested for correctness in case of infinite loops and it proved to be correct.

Comment: I can not answer you without knowing what's your loop and your user are doing !! There are many things which can make an infinite loop !!

Comment: But this is the problem. It happens in different parts of the game, it's not tied to a particular screen or menu, stack traces are useless. The only clue I have is that the users were able to successfully click on something just a few seconds prior to the error. And this shouldn't be possible in case of #1502 error.

Comment: First TweenLite is not the cause of the problem, it's just at the end of it. If it was me I would really not care if user did interact 10 seconds before the app timed out, I would concentrate on fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a JaveScript Error. 1 minute before the error happens there is ExternalInterface call to JS function which bugged out. 1 minute later it throws this error out of the blue. I don't have JS error marshalling enabled but this error still got through. The stack is accidental and doesn't have anything to do with the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code. This should help and give some explanations :

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/asyncoperations/